# Listener of rotated Actor

Tags: rotation, libgdx, listener, actor

I have some Actors and Listeners for each of them. The problem is that if i dont rotate the Actor everything work's great, but if the Actor has the rotation, for example 5 degrees/frame it's listener not always works, like if i miss the Actor and dont click right on it, even if i click right on it. And it happens randomly. What can be the problem?
I've tried changing location of rotation updating etc but nothing helps.

First i've updated the rotation right before drawing like this and tought it was the problem but changing this didnt help. So I dont know what can be the problem.

```
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha){
    rotateBy(angle);
    batch.setColor(getColor());
    batch.draw(toDraw, getX(), getY(), getCenterX(),getCenterY(), getWidth(), getHeight(), 1, 1, getRotation());
}
```

Comment: So, I've done some experements with rotation and everything works great only if Actor is not rotated. In other case there apears random factor and Listener doesn't work always. You can click 10 times and only 5 clicks will be registered.

Answer (score 0):

not that kind of actor you mean, but this is an example I hope you help

```
Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin/uiskin.json"));

TextButton buton = new TextButton("Hola_Mundo", skin);
Container container = new Container(buton);

container.setCenterPosition(800, 480);
container.setTransform(true);
container.rotateBy(60);

.//

YourStage.addActor(container);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(YourStage);
```

Comment: Can I somehow use .setTransform without using Countaner?